# SAS - Reading a specific file from a FTP location

Tags: ftp, sas

I am able to read my files from the FTP location if I specify the exact filename. My problem is that I'm trying to automate this process where I have to read these files week over week and the filename changes randomly. There is no specific pattern to it, so it can't be predetermined.

Is there a way in SAS where I can read the name of all the files present at an FTP location and give the user a dialog box with this information, for them to enter the filename they want to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SAS Display Manager interface you can use a data step `WINDOW` or macro `%WINDOW` statements to define a simple picker, and `DISPLAY` or `%DISPLAY` to raise it.  The simple picker is really simple, no scrollers or other modern adornments.

An FTP folder listing is retrieved using the filename `FTP` engine option `LS`

Sample code:

```
/**/
* location of FTP folder;
filename folder ftp 
  user = 'anonymous'
  host = 'ftp.cdc.gov'
  cd = '/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Publications/ICD9-CM/2011'
  ls
;

* retrieve listing;
data files;
  infile folder;
  input;
  order + 1;
  fileinfo = _infile_;
run;

/**/

%macro picker(
  /* Dynamically build a %WINDOW definition, display it and return the last selected item */
  name=, /* Name of window */
  title=, /* First line text */
  data=, /* data set containing items */
  order=order, /* variable for ordering items in the picker*/
  item=, /* variable to pick a value of */
  result= /* name of macro variable that will contain the picked item, must pre-exist in caller scope */
);

  %* field definitions will look like
  %*  #2 @2 field<i> 1 color=blue attr=rev_video " &filename<i>" ;

  %local n i row field_def;

  proc sql noprint;
    select count(*) into :n trimmed from &data;
    %do i = 1 %to &n;
      %local field&i item&i;
    %end;

    select
      &order, &item
    into
      :order1-, :item1-
    from
      &data;
  quit;

  %do i = 1 %to &N;
    %let field_def = &field_def #%eval(&i+1) @2 field&i 1 color=blue attr=rev_video " &&item&i";
  %end;

  %WINDOW PICKER rows=30 columns=80
    #1 @1 "&title. - Mark an item and Press F3"
    &field_def
  ;

  %display PICKER;

  %do i = 1 %to &N;
    %if %length(&&field&i) %then %let &result=&&item&i;
  %end;
%mend;


%let selected=;
%picker(name=PICKER, title=Pick a file, data=files, item=fileinfo, result=selected);

%put &=selected;
```

More sophisticated pickers can be built using SAS/AF.  Other possibilities include Stored Process prompt dialogs, SAS Studio snippets, or a SAS server page.